# UIUpgradeOtherBundleIdentifier ... No documentation found

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I have been scratching my head around the plist identifier :

> UIUpgradeOtherBundleIdentifier

... It might be exactly what I'm looking for to handle some bundle identifier problems i have... but before submitting and hoping it would work, I'd really like to know what it does exactly. But I can't find any documentation.

Anyone knows what this does ? Or even better, have used it, or have the documentation on it ?

Virtual pie and hugs are to be had :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the Apple Developer Forums, read [this thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/100357#100357). In short, an Apple employee there says "it does not do what you expect" and "please don't use it".

And, of course, since it is not documented trying to use it would be grounds for rejection from the App Store anyway.

Comment: Thanks :) I guessed as much, it had just been confusing me, since I need something similar. +50 for you.